# Word or Phrase Meaning False Self-Criticism

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Is there a word or phrase that means "self-criticism that's actually self-praise"? For example, saying something like:

> My kids are so spoiled! It's all my own fault, I just have too much money to spend on them and I give them too much of what they want.

I'm not talking about "first-world problems," which are real (or ironic) complaints about very minor problems.  I'm talking about brags that are worded as apologies.

Answer (score 6):

It’s a **humblebrag**. NOAD defines it as:

> an ostensibly modest or self-deprecating statement whose actual purpose is to draw attention to something of which one is proud.

The article [The 50 Funniest ‘Humble Brags’ on Twitter](https://twistedsifter.com/2011/05/funniest-humble-brags-on-twitter/) mentions different types of humblebrags and gives examples:

> From the, “It’s not a brag, I’m just complaining” humble brag to the, “this isn’t a brag I’m just being self-deprecating” humble brag, the universe is vast and the number of offenders, seemingly limitless.